# Does cron job remain in effect after computer reboots?

Tags: linux, cron

I have set up cron jobs using the following command

```
crontab -e
```

It seems that if a cron job is scheduled to run within the same day (i.e. computer has not been rebooted), then the cron job runs OK. However, if a cron job is scheduled to run several days later (i.e. computer has been rebooted at least once), then the cron job would be missed.

Moreover, every time when I use "crontab -e" to edit the crontab file in the "nano" editor, the top line shows that I am editing a different file, e.g.

```
File : /tmp/crontab.PLwi9Z/crontab
File : /tmp/crontab.degfpN/crontab
File : /tmp/crontab.odqbkT/crontab
```

I want to know that is this normal for crontab and how to schedule a job to run several days later (i.e. after several reboots). I am using an Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 system.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked your cron log to see if there are any errors? Also, make sure that crond is running and not crashing

Comment: I have just added an entry `30 10 4 12 * my_command` in the crontab file to send out a sound and it works. It indicates that the "cron" daemon should be running correctly and `my_command` should be working OK.  I have now modify the entry to `30 10 5 12 * my_command` to see whether my computer would similarly send out a sound tomorrow at 10:30am. I would not edit the crontab file any more and would shut down my computer tonight. From my experience, the cron job tomorrow would be missed after I reboot my computer tomorrow morning.

Comment: I wonder that is it normal for "cron" to forget its entry after reboot, or I have made some other mistakes.

Comment: Moreover, there is only ONE entry in my crontab file, so this entry should not be interfered by other entries.

Comment: Oh, my crontab entry works OK this time. My computer gives a sound today at 10:30am. However, I have previous experience that a crontab entry did not work. Perhaps previously my edited crontab entry had not been installed properly as I have tried not to use "nano" to edit crontab entry, but I could not reproduce the mistake now. Anyway, thanks for anyone who pays attention to this question.

Comment: If you were previously editing using `crontab -e` and a different editor, that is odd.  If you were **directly editing your crontab file** with a different editor, note that that is not a good idea, as `crond` will not automatically notice you have edited it.  Notifying `crond` of the change is another thing `crontab -e` is doing for you, along with syntax checking.  By the way, if you like Hangin on's answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @MadHatter Previously, I had used the command `EDITOR=/usr/bin/gedit crontab -e` to add crontab entry. However, as you have said, this command may not notify `crond` of the change. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: No, what I said was that using `crontab -e` (enivronment notwithstanding) *should* notify `crond`.  In your case it didn't, which is odd; one of life's little mysteries, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Moreover, every time when I use "crontab -e" to edit the crontab file in the "nano" editor, the top line shows that I am editing a different file, e.g

The `crontab -e` command is 'smart', it makes a temporary copy of the file for you to edit. When you save the file it checks that the file is (reasonably) correct before installing it into the correct location on your system.

> I want to know that is this normal for crontab and how to schedule a job to run several days later

If your system is turned off when a crontab entry should run then it will be missed. This is normal. If you have jobs that should run even when they have been missed by the system being powered off then take a look at [anacron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/anacron.8.html).

Comment: Thanks for the "anacron" suggestion. It seems a good tool.